# What is the recommended tire pressure for a sack barrow for different weight intervals?

Tags: transportation

Is there a recommendation for tire pressure of sack barrows (with 200 kg max load)? The pressure can obviously not be maximal (e.g. the maximum of the tire) since that makes it hard to climb stairs. It can also not be too low because this would require increasing the presure if one plans to transport more weight; a recommendation for 2 or max. 3 intervals (e.g. 0 kg to 50 kg, 50 kg to 150 kg and 150 kg to 200 kg) would be appreciated as well.

[Search engine results](https://www.google.de/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=+%09sack+barrow+pressure&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=MET2V8ufNsGBaILSudAB) only reveal information without references or feedback whether the values were approved in usage.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it inflated at or near maximum. Then if you have a task where the barrow needs less pressure you bleed the tire down to the point where it does that job while supporting the load.